# How can i get the data from Swift based IBOutlet UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

```
 @IBOutlet  var firstName:UITextField?
 @IBOutlet  var lastName:UITextField?

 let string = firstName!.text
 print(string)
```

The output is like as below:

`Optional("ohh")`

How can I get the data without optional text and double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `text` attribute of a UITextField is an Optional - this means it must be unwrapped. To do that, you add a `!` to the end, which produces a `String` instead of a `String?`.

You can also conditionally unwrap an optional using the syntax `if let`, so here it would be

```
if let string = firstName!.text{
print(string) //outputs if text exists
}else{
//text didn't exist
}
```

Comment: It is working fine.how can i get the data without if condition.

Comment: print(firstName!.text!)

Comment: @mano - dont do this print(firstName!.text!). There is a reason you need to if let on the optional....

Comment: Also if you know that outlets won't be nil, no reason to mark them as optional. That would save you one unwrap.